# dont want to build again and again

Tags: apache, jsp, ant

I have a webapplication lets say at location

```
C:\Test\MyWeb
```

Every time I make some change I have to rebuild it via `ant package` command. Then I copy the MyWeb.war file into apache's webapp folder.

I want to avoid this build and copy thing after every change. How to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an IDE like eclipse and start your application from within the IDE.
The IDE should automatically recompile your files and in most case can do a hot replace of the code so you don't need to restart.

Answer (score 0):

For development environment, server supports something like `HOT Deployment`. You can deploy an exploded directory of the web application.

Making following changes to web application will automatically reflected. Sometimes some servers might restart application for some of these changes. But, you dont have to package and deploy for every change.

- Adding new Jsp's
- Modifying web.xml
- Modifying Jsp's or Servlets