# Updated servlet class not being referred in tomcat ubuntu

Tags: servlets, ubuntu, tomcat6

I am beginner to servlets. I am trying to create and run servlets using tomcat in ubuntu. I am facing a problem. I am able to call the servlet from the html file by adding an entries into web.xml. But when I change the java program a little and recompile and invoke the new servlet class, the html still seems to call the old one.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are redeploying the application properly.

Tomcat by default supports `HOT Deployment`, you should check if the modified servlet got reflected in `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/{application-name}/WEB-INF/classes` location.

.

**References:**

- [How do i update JSP's without restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317469/how-do-i-update-my-jsp-files-without-restarting-the-whole-jboss-server/11322579#11322579)
- [Hot Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132817/dont-want-to-build-again-and-again/11133628#11133628)
- [Hot Deployment Support in WebLogic and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996977/jsp-deployment-without-war-file/10997149#10997149)